# how can i put a chart in a div with *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, chart.js

i'm new to chart.js but i managed to creatr a chart as i wanted it, now i tried to create two tab buttons so that i can show some tables when i press a tab button and the chart when i press the other tab button, to do this i use a *ngIf command, but when i try to do what i've just wrote i get an error:

> Chart.js:9369 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

... i don't understand why i get it since if i remove the ngIf and try to see all the content(the tables and the chart) i get no error...
please see that in the chart i use the datas in the tables.
i'm sorry if my english is not good but i can try to explain better in the comments
here i paste the code of my html

```
     <div>
    <button class="tablink" style="float: left;" (click)="ana(false)">DATI TABELLARI</button>
    <button class="tablink" style="float: right;" (click)="ana(true)">GRAFICO</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="showAna!=true && loading==false">
 TABLES
</div>
<div *ngIf="showAna==true && loading==false">
    CHART
    <div id="divCh">
        <canvas id="chart">
            {{chart}}
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the ts file:

```
 async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
 HERE I GET THE DATAS THAT I NEED FOR MY TABLES AND THEN FOR THE CHART

 this.chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: this.mesi,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'totale va ufficiali',
      data: this.totEffortva, 
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: "white",
        pointBackgroundColor: "black",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "brown",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "yellow",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 4,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
    },{
      label: "totale giornate impegnate",
      fill: true,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(167,105,0,0.4)",
      borderColor: "rgb(167, 105, 0)",
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "white",
      pointBackgroundColor: "black",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "brown",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "yellow",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      // notice the gap in the data and the spanGaps: false
      data: this.totprog,
      spanGaps: false,
    }]
  },
  
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
      }
    }
  },

});
this.loading=false;
 }
  ana(show:boolean){
     this.showAna=show
 }
```

I repeat: if i don't use ngif for show what i want whit the buttons it works fine, if i use it i get the error

> Chart.js:9369 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `ngOnInit()` is called  there is no `canvas` element in the DOM since `*ngIf` condition is false by default.
What you need - move ChartJS initialization logic to another place (you can use another life hook method like `ngAfterViewChecked` to check if canvas element is rendered or not, or call this logic by user event) and only after that initialize ChartJS

as alternative, you can replace `*ngIf` with `[class.hidden]="!showAna"`. Do not forget add `.hidden { display: none }` to css file

Comment: thank you but where should i put ngAfterViewChecked? and what exactly should i move and where? thank you again

Comment: as alternative, you can replace *ngIf with `[class.hidden]="!showAna"`. Do not forget add `.hidden { display: none }` to css file

Comment: the solution in the last comment worked for me, thank you :)